# What is the logic of Following and Followers Systems?

Tags: mysql, database-design, twitter

I'm woking on some project and I thinking about the follower and following system like twitter.I have members table on database.How can I do follower system.Whats is the logic?I worked about something like that: I created new table that name is following and i have 3 rows.These rows are id,user_id,follower_id. is that enough for me? I have not idea about how can do this system? Can you help me?

Comment: This seems a perfectly acceptable design. You can find followers of a user by searching for that user in 'user_id' and find who a user follows by searching for that user in 'follower_id'. You may wish to include some extra metadata such as a timestamp, so you know when the relationship was last updated. You may also wish to track when the relationship started or ended, depending on your use case.

Comment: _"I created new table that name is following and i have 3 rows"_ - you mean "3 **columns**"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that design is sufficient for a simple following system such as that of Twitter. Of course, some extra data (such as the timestamp, as suggested by @Ina) could be useful and you don't strictly need the `id` in it.

I'd recommend something like:

```
userID INT PRIMARY,
followID INT PRIMARY,
creationTime DATETIME
```

Answer (score 5):

"Follows" (or "is followed by") is a relationship between two user entities which your table reflects.

This means that unless you are planning to treat multiple follows and unfollows between the same users as separate entries, you don't even need the `id`.

Make the `user_id` and `follower_id` reference `user` with a `FOREIGN KEY`, make them both a composite primary key and create index on `follower_id` (to get a list of users one follows fast):

```
CREATE TABLE
        follows
        (
        user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES user (id),
        follower_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES user (id),
        PRIMARY KEY
                (user_id, follower_id)
        KEY follower_id (follower_id)
        )
ENGINE=InnoDB -- if you want the foreign keys to work
```

You may add other attributes as well.

If you want to track follows and unfollows between the same users then you need to promote this into an entity, adding a surrogate primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE
        follows
        (
        id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES user (id),
        follower_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES user (id),

        -- These are additional attributes

        follows_from DATETIME NOT NULL,
        follows_till DATETIME,

        --

        KEY follower_id (follower_id),
        KEY user_id (user_id)
        )
ENGINE=InnoDB -- if you want the foreign keys to work
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a single entity of `People`, you need to create a many-to-many relationship from `People` to `People`.  In your association table, you'll have two columns, `PeopleID` and `Following`.

To find followers of a user, search for that user's id in the `Following` column.
To list who a user is following, search in the `PeopleID` column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a site where users log in, you'll want to add a table to your database with two columns, either 'friend1' and 'friend2' (assuming friendship is a bidirectional relation) or 'leader' and 'follower' (for the unidirectional relationship of a subscription). Then, you'll want a short PHP script which takes friend1 and friend2 as inputs (for example, as POST or GET variables) and enters that pair in the database. Finally, add a button on your website that either makes an AJAX call to that PHP script, or is part of an HTML form whose target is that PHP script.